# Can a stored procedure be used as a parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, insert

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE (aNumber, aDate) VALUES ((aSproc param1, param2) , myDate)
```

I need to pass a stored procedure with parameters as a parameter of an insert statement. Is this possible?

Comment: You should tried it and let us know...

Comment: I did try and I can't make it work, that's why I posted this question.

Comment: What kind of person would down vote a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on what the stored procedure returns. Stored procedures return the table that results from the last select that is issued in the SP. So if your SP ends with `SELECT NULL` then your SP will return NULL and then your insert will return NULL. For what you have to work, you have to make sure that the stored procedure returns ONLY one value i.e. a table that is one row and one column.

The reason for this is because your insert is expecting a single value to be part of its value clause and you are probably returning multiple rows and multiple columns. You can test this by ending your SP with `SELECT 1` which would return the int to your insert which would then have a value type it could understand as part of its value clause.

Also posting your SP would help us debug it.

Comment: Thanks John. The sproc returns a single value and if I do the insert with just ONE column in the INSERT INTO statement it works. What I can't figure out is how to have the sproc AND another parameter in the INSERT INTO statement with out SQL Server complaining.

So, it's not the sproc I'm having trouble with, it's using it as a parameter of an INSERT INTO statement that I'm having trouble with...

Comment: You could always use a variable to store the results of your SP and then set the variable into the INSERT statement.

Comment: @MrCoincidence But this is tough to help solve without seeing your stored procedure

Comment: Thanks again John. I just changed the sproc to return BOTH values and now it's working... I do appreciate you answering though!

Comment: @MrCoincidence Cool if you can post the answer you used or send out some upvotes or whatever, so that there is a record for the next programmer. Cheers dude.

Comment: Well, I don't have the answer to my question. I never did figure out how to pass a call to a stored procedure as a parameter of an INSERT INTO statement.